# Window doesn't get focus when using Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint flag

Tags: c++, qt

I need to create window, which always stays on top without borders and controls. So I did this:

```
MainWindow window;
window.show();
```

Where MainWindow class looks like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent, 
Qt::Window | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint 
| Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint) {

}

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    if(event->key() == Qt::Key_Escape){
        QApplication::exit();
    } else
        QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```

Which works, but not perfectly. After program is launched, the windows doesn't have focus, so you must first click on it.If I remove `Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint`, window gains the focus, but than it doesn't show at all workspaces (desktops).

**Question 1:** What does `Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint` actually do?

**Question 2:** How do I get this working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I managed to dig through the docs.

**Question 1:** `Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint` results in window without border and no control from window manager at all (only at X11!).

**Question 2:** To get focus and enable keyboard input, it is necessary to call `QWidget::activateWindow()`.

Comment: In the wayland platform, I receive this message "qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()". Then when calling  QGuiApplication::focusWindow() it returns null. It seems relevant to the asked question. Can you give some help?